# Attempting to Decrypt an AES-256-CBC Encrypted File but Decryption Password isn't known

Tags: command-line, 16.04, password, encryption, openssl

I am trying to decrypt a password protected file that was encrypted using AES-256-CBC, but the password to decrypt the file has been forgotten.

In this simulation, I do know the password is a dictionary word, and I have a word list to try a dictionary attack against the password. I also know that no salt was used when encrypting the file. But I am unsure on how to find the right method to do this.

My mind keeps going to JTR, but I need to use OpenSSL commands. I would appreciate the help!

I am using OpenSSL 1.1.1 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Which "JTR"? https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/JTR

Comment: @waltinator Most likely John the Ripper: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_the_Ripper

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple shell script to iterate through your dictionary file (search on StackOverflow if you don't know how).

Then use this command to attempt decryption: ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31552829/5837178))

`openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -k $password -in encrypted.data -out un_encrypted.data`

You will also need some method to decide whether the decrypted data is of the format you expect. The `file` command could be useful.